# JavaFX issue when starting the GUI

Tags: java

I started a JavaFX project in IntelliJ and created a GUI in with the Scene Builder.
Didn't add any line of code by myself yet, all of it is generated automatically depending on what I've built in regard of the design.

Unfortunatly I can't even start it.

**This is my main class:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

   @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
       Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
       primaryStage.setTitle("WowImporter");
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
       primaryStage.show();
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
       launch(args);
   }

}
```

**This is the fxml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF;" vgap="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="772.0" prefWidth="510.0">
         <children>
            <VBox layoutX="9.0" layoutY="177.0" prefHeight="189.0" prefWidth="126.0">
               <children>
                  <Label prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="122.0" text="Was wird importiert?">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Separator prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="115.0" text="Anzahl WE-Stellen:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Separator prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="126.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="116.0" text="Quellpfad:" textAlignment="CENTER">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <Separator prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="119.0" />
                  <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="114.0" text="Zielpfad:">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <VBox layoutX="151.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="190.0" prefWidth="338.0">
               <children>
                  <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Pläne" />
                  <Separator prefHeight="8.0" prefWidth="338.0" />
                  <CheckBox mnemonicParsing="false" text="Galerie" />
                  <Separator prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="338.0" />
                  <Spinner prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="59.0" />
                  <Separator prefHeight="14.0" prefWidth="338.0" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
            <ImageView fitHeight="113.0" fitWidth="356.0" layoutX="79.0" layoutY="42.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@Bilder/wowi-logo-2017.jpg" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <Button layoutX="276.0" layoutY="388.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="94.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #000000; -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Importieren">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button layoutX="162.0" layoutY="388.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="94.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #000000; -fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-border-color: #000000; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Scannen">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <View layoutX="28.0" layoutY="449.0" prefHeight="302.0" prefWidth="456.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

And my Controller class is yet empty.

**These are the error messages I get:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\b.ummak\Downloads\openjfx-15.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=54847:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\b.ummak\IdeaProjects\WowImporterNEU\out\production\WowImporterNEU;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" sample.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/b.ummak/IdeaProjects/WowImporterNEU/out/production/WowImporterNEU/sample/sample.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2949)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2793)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2758)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2624)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3323)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3280)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3249)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3222)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3199)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3192)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:3017)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:3006)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2947)
    ... 20 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would be very happy if someone of you could help me with that issue. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: You're missing a library that contains `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View`  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47307101/9233560) may help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK guys I found the error myself.
It's this one:

There is a Gluon package called Gluon Mobile which you have to purchase for a few of the elements you use with the Scene Builder.

I was using the "View" element and that one needs the Gluon Mobile package which I didn't have and of course he couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this import

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
```

or
add gluon jar lib
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47676001/7513880) more help

Answer (score -1):

Here is a very simple and step by step process. Go through this link [Sample example of JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm) you will find your missing steps.

Comment: Hi Jimmy,
thanks for your answer. But I already did all of the steps mentioned :(